# Why is this method in a Spring Data repository considered a query method?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

We have implemented an application that should be able to use either JPA, Couchbase or MongoDB. (for now, may increase in the future). We successfully implemented JPA and Couchbase by separating repositories for each e.g. JPA  will come from org.company.repository.jpa while couchbase will come from org.company.repository.cb. All repository interfaces extends a common repository found in org.company.repository. We are now targeting MongoDB by creating a new package org.company.repository.mongo. However we are encountering this error:

```
No property updateLastUsedDate found for type TokenHistory!
```

Here are our codes:

```
@Document
public class TokenHistory extends BaseEntity {
    private String subject;
    private Date lastUpdate;
    // Getters and setters here...
}
```

Under org.company.repository.TokenHistoryRepository.java

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface TokenHistoryRepository<ID extends Serializable> extends TokenHistoryRepositoryCustom, BaseEntityRepository<TokenHistory, ID> {
    // No problem here. Handled by Spring Data
    TokenHistory findBySubject(@Param("subject") String subject);
}
// The custom method
interface TokenHistoryRepositoryCustom {
    void updateLastUsedDate(@Param("subject") String subject);
}
```

Under org.company.repository.mongo.TokenHistoryMongoRepository.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "/token-history")
public interface TokenHistoryMongoRepository extends TokenHistoryRepository<String> {

    TokenHistory findBySubject(@Param("subject") String subject);
}

class TokenHistoryMongoRepositoryCustomImpl {
    public void updateLastUsedDate(String subject) {
        //TODO implement this
    }
}
```

And for Mongo Configuration

```
@Configuration
@Profile("mongo")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {
    "org.company.repository.mongo"
}, repositoryImplementationPostfix = "CustomImpl",
    repositoryBaseClass = BaseEntityRepositoryMongoImpl.class
)
public class MongoConfig {
}
```

Setup is the same for both JPA and Couchbase but we didn't encountered that error. It was able to use the inner class with "CustomImpl" prefix, which should be the case base on the documentations.

Is there a problem in my setup or configuration for MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TokenHistoryMongoRepositoryCustomImpl` doesn't actually implement the `TokenHistoryRepositoryCustom` interface, which means that there's no way for us to find out that `updateLastUsedDate(…)` in the class found is considered to be an implementation of the interface method. Hence, it's considered a query method and then triggers the query derivation.

I highly doubt that this works for the other stores as claimed as the code inspecting query methods is shared in `DefaultRepositoryInformation`.